# Detect save page to disk

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Just like there's `window.onbeforeprint` to determine if the user is trying to print, is there a similar web API to define a callback when the user is about to save current page to disk (*File/ Save as*)?

The use case would be the same: being able to make changes to the page before it gets saved.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window), there is not.

There is only one method when "saving for mobile" (aka: adding the icon to the home page) called [onbeforeinstallprompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/onbeforeinstallprompt), but I don't think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21488750)

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij kind of hard to put in the answer if the answer is essentially “it’s not on the contents of this link”...

Comment: I could be wrong with this review of your post. Many reviewers will check it to find consensus it and if I am wrong I will be punished (with temporal ban) :) IMHO answer on SO should be a "small interesting story" and content direct answer, all other could be a comment.